# ImportMany of MEF loading Contracts twice

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mef, caliburn.micro

I have two classes which Exports `IScreen`, but when I import the same using

```
[ImportMany(typeof(IScreen))]
private IEnumerable<Lazy<IScreen,IJIMSMetadata>> _modules;
public IEnumerable<Lazy<IScreen, IJIMSMetadata>> Modules
{
        get { return _modules; }
}
```

The Modules contain four instance of IScreen, but I have Exported only two.

This is Container

```
container = new CompositionContainer(
                new AggregateCatalog(AssemblySource.Instance.Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)))                
                );


protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
{
    string _modulePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Modules");
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(_modulePath, "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    List<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
    assemblies.Add(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        assemblies.Add(Assembly.LoadFrom(file));
    }
    return assemblies;
}
```

Comment: Tell us how you are building your CompositionContainer

Comment: The container loads only one class using assemby.load from

Comment: Wild guess, but is your assembly located somewhere where recursing through its location would load "the same assembly" twice. E.g. It recurses through `Debug` and `Release` folders?

Comment: No, the saasembly is only loaded once

Comment: Can you show us how/where you export `IScreen`?

Comment: I also faced a similar problem. Dll was loaded only once, but class twice. The problem was that I had class in two files, divided by partial directive. And each definition was preceded by the attribute [Export (typeof (IMyInterface)]), and that was a problem. The MEF load the class as many times as the Export attribute is defined.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using an AggregateCatalog, check to be sure you are not adding both an AssemblyCatalog and a DirectoryCatalog for the location containing the executing assembly.

For example, the following code avoids processing the same assembly twice.

```
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
var locations = new List<string>();
foreach (var loc in GetPluginDirectories())
    if (!locations.Contains(loc))
    {
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(loc));
        locations.Add(loc);
    }

var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
if (!locations.Contains(Path.GetDirectoryName(asm.Location)))
    catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(asm));
```